My character keeps moving on his own even without any keyboard input
https://imgur.com/EabxPcA
As you can see from the video above, my character moves on his own constantly even without keyboard input. It's simply guided by my Camera3D. I have a feeling I know the source of the error, the get_facing_direction function always returns the vector, (0, 0, 1) at minimum, so there is no ZERO vector at all. I tried forcing a ZERO vector by making use of if statements, so that if there is no keyboard input then use a ZERO vector as the direction vector. However, that didn't work well since whenever I try clicking the keys it would follow the directions of the x and z axis, instead of following where the camera is facing.
extends CharacterBody3D

signal noInput

@export var speed = 5.0
@export var jump_speed = 4.5
@export var g = 12.81

var camera3dScript = Camera3D.new()

# Get the gravity from the project settings to be synced with RigidBody nodes.
var gravity = ProjectSettings.get_setting("physics/3d/default_gravity")

var theVelocity = Vector3.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
    
    $"../CameraPivot".position = position
    var direction = $"../CameraPivot/Camera3D".get_facing_direction() 
    # Add the gravity.
    # print(gravity)
    #var direction = camera3dScript.get_facing_direction()
    #print(direction)
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        direction.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_up"):
        direction.z -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_down"):
        direction.z += 1
        
    if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
        direction = direction.normalized()
        $Pivot.basis = Basis.looking_at(direction)
    
    theVelocity.x = direction.x * speed
    theVelocity.z = direction.z * speed
    
    if not is_on_floor():
        theVelocity.y -= g * delta
    elif is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        theVelocity.y = jump_speed

    velocity = theVelocity
    move_and_slide()

Above is the CharacterBody3D code, and below is the Camera3D code,
extends Camera3D

# Sensitivity of the mouse
var sensitivity = 0.1

# Rotation angles
var rotation_x = 0.0
var rotation_y = 0.0

func _ready():
    # Capture the mouse pointer
    Input.set_mouse_mode(Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED)

func get_facing_direction():
    # The direction the camera is facing is the negative z-axis of the camera's transform
    #print(-global_transform.basis.z)
    return -global_transform.basis.z

func _unhandled_input(event):
    #print(event)
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        var direction = get_facing_direction()
        #print("Camera is facing: ", direction)
        _rotate_camera(event.relative)
        

func _rotate_camera(mouse_delta):
    # Update rotation angles based on mouse movement
    rotation_x -= mouse_delta.y * 1
    rotation_y -= mouse_delta.x * 1
    
    # Clamp the x rotation to avoid flipping the camera
    rotation_x = clamp(rotation_x, -90, 90 )
    
    # Apply rotation
    rotation_degrees = Vector3(rotation_x, rotation_y, 0)

Any help is appreciated, and thank you!
